# Understanding how words are stored in dictionary of gensim corpus after using "gensim.corpora.Dictionary(TEXT)"

Tags: python, gensim, corpus

After converting a list of text documents to corpora dictionary and then converting it to a bag of words model using:

```
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(docs) # docs is a list of text documents
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docs]
```

We can find out the index value of particular words in the dictionary using:

```
dictionary.doc2idx(["righteous","height"])
```

Is there any way to find the word stored in dictionary at particular index?

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:**

`dictionary.get(index_of_word)`

Example:

```
import gensim

docs=[['hello', 'world'],['i','am', 'groot']]

dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(docs) # docs is a list of text documents
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docs]

print(dictionary.get(0))
print(dictionary.get(3))
```

Output:

```
hello
groot
```

Hope that helps!